ScrollView not working after collecting data from API
Im learning react native and cant get my page to scroll, I have tried to simplify it and use simple text and not my call back but literally nothing is working
Any help would be great
My results screen:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import RenderHTML from 'react-native-render-html';

const ProgressScreen = ({ route }) => {
    const { plan, loading, error } = route.params || {};
    const [parsedPlan, setParsedPlan] = useState(null);
    const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (plan) {
            try {
                const parsedData = JSON.parse(plan);
                setParsedPlan(parsedData);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Error parsing plan data:', e);
            }
        }
    }, [plan]);

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" />
                <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Loading...</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    if (error) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    if (!parsedPlan) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.errorText}>No plan data available</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContent}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>{parsedPlan.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.greetingText}>{parsedPlan.greeting}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Ingredients:</Text>
            {parsedPlan.ingredients && (
                <RenderHTML
                    contentWidth={width}
                    source={{ html: parsedPlan.ingredients }}
                    baseStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
                />
            )}
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Instructions:</Text>
            {parsedPlan.instructions && (
                <RenderHTML
                    contentWidth={width}
                    source={{ html: parsedPlan.instructions }}
                    baseStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
                />
            )}
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Nutritional Value:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.nutritionalText}>{parsedPlan.nutritional_value}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(9, 9, 11)',
    },
    scrollContent: {
        padding: 20,  // padding for the content inside the ScrollView
    },
    loadingText: {
        color: '#fff',
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    errorText: {
        color: 'red',
    },
    titleText: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: '#fff',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    greetingText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#fff',
        marginBottom: 20,
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#fff',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    nutritionalText: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#fff',
        marginTop: 10,
    },
});

export default ProgressScreen;

for context my screen thats navigating us to the progressScreen
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, Button, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

const CustomCheckbox = ({isChecked, onPress}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.checkboxBase, isChecked && styles.checkboxChecked]}>
            {isChecked && <View style={styles.checkboxInner} />}
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const MainScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
    const [selectedPeople, setSelectedPeople] = useState('1');
    const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({
        lowFODMAP: false,
        glutenFree: false,
        dairyFree: false,
        vegetarian: false,
        vegan: false,
        lowCalorie: false,
    });
    const handleCookPress = async () => {
    try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await axios.post('endpoint', {
            content: textInput,
            fodmap: checkboxes.lowFODMAP || false,
            dairy: checkboxes.dairyFree || false,
            gluten: checkboxes.glutenFree || false,
            veggie: checkboxes.vegetarian || false,
            vegan: checkboxes.vegan || false,
            calorie: checkboxes.lowCalorie || false,
            people: selectedPeople || 1,
        });


        if (response.data.status === 200) {
            setLoading(false);
            navigation.navigate('ProgressScreen', { plan: response.data.data, loading: false });
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
            navigation.navigate('ProgressScreen', { error: response.data.message, loading: false });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Axios error:', error.response || error.message);
        navigation.navigate('ProgressScreen', { error: 'An error occurred', loading: false });
    }
};
    const handleCheckboxChange = (key) => {
        setCheckboxes({...checkboxes, [key]: !checkboxes[key]});
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                source={{uri: '/img/icon.fb33606c.png'}} // Replace with your image URL
                style={styles.image}
                resizeMode="contain"
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="I would like to make a cherry pie..."
                placeholderTextColor="#ccc"
                value={textInput}
                onChangeText={setTextInput}
            />
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <CustomCheckbox
                    isChecked={checkboxes.lowFODMAP}
                    onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange('lowFODMAP')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Low FODMAP</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <CustomCheckbox
                    isChecked={checkboxes.glutenFree}
                    onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange('glutenFree')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Gluten and Wheat Free</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <CustomCheckbox
                    isChecked={checkboxes.dairyFree}
                    onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange('dairyFree')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Dairy Free</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <CustomCheckbox
                    isChecked={checkboxes.vegetarian}
                    onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange('vegetarian')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Vegetarian</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <CustomCheckbox
                    isChecked={checkboxes.vegan}
                    onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange('vegan')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Vegan</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                <CustomCheckbox
                    isChecked={checkboxes.lowCalorie}
                    onPress={() => handleCheckboxChange('lowCalorie')}
                />
                <Text style={styles.label}>Low Calorie</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={handleCookPress}
            disabled={loading} // Optionally disable the button while loading
        >
            {loading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#ffffff" />
            ) : (
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get me a recipe</Text>
            )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(9, 9, 11)',
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
        marginBottom: 20,
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    input: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        color: '#fff',
        padding: 10,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    checkboxContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    label: {
        marginLeft: 8,
        color: '#fff',
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(140, 7, 24)',
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    checkboxBase: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    checkboxChecked: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    checkboxInner: {
        width: 12,
        height: 12,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(140, 7, 24)',
    },
});

export default MainScreen;

I have tried to use just lipsum text and not use API data but its not working.
